# Extract text from wrk output

Tags: jenkins, awk, sed, graylog2, wrk

I'm running a load test with wrk2 as a job on Jenkins. I'd like to send the results of the load test to Graylog but I only want to store the Requests/Sec and average latency.

Here's what the output looks like:

```
Running 30s test @ https://example.com

1 threads and 100 connections
  Thread calibration: mean lat.: 8338.285ms, rate sampling interval: 19202ms
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency    16.20s     6.17s   29.64s    65.74%
    Req/Sec     5.00      0.00     5.00    100.00%
  Latency Distribution (HdrHistogram - Recorded Latency)
 50.000%   15.72s 
 75.000%   20.81s 
 90.000%   24.58s 
 99.000%   29.13s 
 99.900%   29.66s 
 99.990%   29.66s 
 99.999%   29.66s 
100.000%   29.66s 

  Detailed Percentile spectrum:
       Value   Percentile   TotalCount 1/(1-Percentile)

    4497.407     0.000000            1         1.00
    7561.215     0.100000           11         1.11
   11100.159     0.200000           22         1.25
   12582.911     0.300000           33         1.43
   14565.375     0.400000           44         1.67
   15720.447     0.500000           54         2.00
   16416.767     0.550000           60         2.22
   17301.503     0.600000           65         2.50
   18464.767     0.650000           71         2.86
   19185.663     0.700000           76         3.33
   20807.679     0.750000           81         4.00
   21479.423     0.775000           84         4.44
   22347.775     0.800000           87         5.00
   22527.999     0.825000           90         5.71
   23216.127     0.850000           93         6.67
   23478.271     0.875000           95         8.00
   23805.951     0.887500           96         8.89
   24723.455     0.900000           98        10.00
   25067.519     0.912500           99        11.43
   25395.199     0.925000          101        13.33
   26525.695     0.937500          102        16.00
   26525.695     0.943750          102        17.78
   26705.919     0.950000          103        20.00
   28065.791     0.956250          104        22.86
   28065.791     0.962500          104        26.67
   28377.087     0.968750          105        32.00
   28377.087     0.971875          105        35.56
   28475.391     0.975000          106        40.00
   28475.391     0.978125          106        45.71
   28475.391     0.981250          106        53.33
   29130.751     0.984375          107        64.00
   29130.751     0.985938          107        71.11
   29130.751     0.987500          107        80.00
   29130.751     0.989062          107        91.43
   29130.751     0.990625          107       106.67
   29655.039     0.992188          108       128.00
   29655.039     1.000000          108          inf
#[Mean    =    16199.756, StdDeviation   =     6170.105]
#[Max     =    29638.656, Total count    =          108]
#[Buckets =           27, SubBuckets     =         2048]
----------------------------------------------------------
  130 requests in 30.02s, 13.44MB read
  Socket errors: connect 0, read 0, write 0, timeout 1192
Requests/sec:      4.33
Transfer/sec:    458.47KB
```

Does anyone know how I could go about extracting Requests/sec (at the bottom) and the latency average to send as JSON parameters?

The expected output would be: `"latency": 16.2, "requests_per_second": 4.33`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't provide the expected output so your question isn't clear but is this what you want?

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{a["Latency"]; a["Requests/sec:"]} ($1 in a) && ($2 ~ /[0-9]/){print $1, $2}' file
Latency 16.20s
Requests/sec: 4.33
```

Updated based on you adding expected output to your question:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { map["Latency"]="latency"; map["Requests/sec:"]="requests_per_second" }
    ($1 in map) && ($2 ~ /[0-9]/) { printf "%s\"%s\": %s", ofs, map[$1], $2+0; ofs=", " }
    END { print "" }
' file
"latency": 16.2, "requests_per_second": 4.33
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, and apologies for not making the question clearer with expected output - I've added that now. This looks it might work anyway if I combine it with jq.

Comment: I updated my answer based on your new provided expected output.